# ¿Como puedo llevar informacion de un ts al mismo ts pero con diferentes export?

Tags: angular

Tengo este documento ts que tiene 2 export class que seria como tener 2 ts en 1 como llevo informacion de uno al otro? ejemplo como llevaria la informacion de this.manuales que se encuentra en ManualesComponent a el contructor de DialogContentExampleDialog que se encuentra un poco mas abajo?

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 // primer ts
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-manuales',
          templateUrl: './manuales.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./manuales.component.scss']
        })
        export class ManualesComponent implements OnInit {
        
          manuales: any;
          
          constructor() { 
                         this.manuales = "Hola...."
                         }
        }

        // este seria como otro ts
        @Component({
          selector: 'dialog-content-example-dialog',
          templateUrl: 'dialog-content-example-dialog.html',
        })
        export class DialogContentExampleDialog {
          
          videos:any;
        
          constructor() {
            this.videos = "Hola que hace"
          }
        }
```

En dialog-content-example-dialog.html

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Video</h2><br>
{{videos}}
<!--Y tambien quisiera que se mostrara el this.manuales-->
```

Comment: Cuando llamas al modal, desde donde lo haces es decir. Desde el dialog-content-example-dialog.html haces el llamado al 1Archivo.html ?? de ser así como haces eso, a nivel de código. Dependiendo de lo que respondas así mismo podemos mirar si la opción que te dan en la respuesta te sirve o es mas apropiado hacer uso del paso de información entre componentes que maneja angular

Comment: @jorgeGomez re formule la pregunta

Comment: ambos ts los tienes creados en un mismo archivo según entiendo. A nivel de HTML cual es la info que se muestra y como le cargas el modal, si no me comprendes, procederé a darte un ejemplo

Comment: @jorgeGomez ya edite para que veas el html. digamos la informacion de un ts al otro para usarla en el html que indico ahi

Comment: Estas usando material, esta libreria ya te proporciona los servicios para pasar datos del component al dialogo. Mira este ejemplo https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basandome en que mencionas que tienes 2 clases en un mismo ts. Te comparto una forma, pero no es la que te recomiendo, la cual sería la siguiente:

***El ts quedaría de la siguiente manera para el ejemplo:***

```js
import { AfterContentInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Creamos una variable global
var globalVideos: any = null;

/**
 * Implementamos la interfaz AfterContentInit para este ejemplo
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-manuales',
  templateUrl: './manuales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manuales.component.css']
})
export class ManualesComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  manuales: any;
  videos: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.manuales = 'Hola....';
  }
  
  /**
   * En el metodo ngAfterContentInit de la interfaz AfterContentInit
   * Agregamos un console.log donde vamos  aimprimir los valores de la variable manuales
   * y la variable global globalVideos que se encuentra fuera de la clase.
   * Elegimos este metodo debido a que se ejecuta despues de cargar el contenido de nuestro componente.
   */
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.videos = globalVideos;
    console.log(this.manuales, this.videos);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-content-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-content-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogContentExampleDialog {
  
  videos:any;

  /**
   * En el constructor le damos un valor a la variable globalVideos
   */
  constructor() {
    this.videos = "Hola que hace"
    globalVideos = this.videos;
  }
}
```

***El html de manuales quedaría de la siguiente manera:***

```html
<p>manuales works!</p>
<p>Videos: {{videos}}</p>
<!-- Aqui agregamos el selector de nuestro segundo componente creado -->
<dialog-content-example-dialog></dialog-content-example-dialog>
```

*La Segunda forma como puedes hacerlo y que considero más apropiada hacerlo es la siguiente:*

***El ts para la prueba seria de la siguiente manera:***

```js
// Importamos las interfaces requeridas
import { AfterContentInit, Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Implementamos la interfaz AfterContentInit para este ejemplo
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-manuales',
  templateUrl: './manuales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manuales.component.css']
})
export class ManualesComponent implements OnInit {

  manuales: any;
  videos: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.manuales = 'Hola....';
  }

  /**
   * Creamos un metodo el cual va a ser publico y recibe un parametro tipo any
   * este parametro va a ser el valor que se envia desde el otro componente aqui tomamos esa
   * informacion y se la almacenamos a la variable que designamos con el mismo nombre que es videos
   * @param res
   */
  obtenerResultado(res: any) {
    this.videos = res;
    console.log(this.videos);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-content-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-content-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogContentExampleDialog implements AfterContentInit {
  
  // Creamos una variable de salida, el cual nos permite mandar informacion obtenida en este componente al componente padre
  @Output() public resultado: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  videos:any;

  // Inicializamos la variable en el constructor
  constructor() {
    this.videos = 'Hola que hace';
  }

  // Transmitimos la informacion de la variable videos
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.resultado.emit(this.videos);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

***El Html se vería así:***

```html
<p>manuales works!</p>
<p *ngIf="videos !== undefined">Videos: {{videos}}</p>
<!-- Aqui agregamos el selector de nuestro segundo componente creado -->
<!-- Agregamos el nuevo atributo que creamos en el componente que llama resultado, como va a mandar informacion debe colocarse en parentesis -->
<!-- como expresion colocamos la funcion obtenerResultado que creamos en el componente manuales y le agregamos el parametro como $event, para transmitir la informacion que mandan desde el componente hijo -->
<dialog-content-example-dialog (resultado)="obtenerResultado($event);"></dialog-content-example-dialog>
```

Prueba a ver como te va y si te ha quedado claro. Espero te sirva.

Para que lo tengas presente.

1. De la primer forma, puedes hacerlo, pro te toca manualmente hacer que el componente Manuales revise los cambios que surgen en la variabl `globalVideos`
2. De la segunda forma, no te debes preocupar por estar pendientes ya que a lo que surgen cambios en la variable y las emites a resultados, inmediatamente se ejecuta el metodo obtenerResultado y le transmite al componente manuales la información de videos.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo si funciono

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es utilizar comunicación entre componentes y servicios.
En tu caso, se podría importar un servicio VideoService en el componente donde se usa la función openDialog. Cuando se llame a la función seteamos una variable url en el servicio, para después recogerla en DialogContentExampleDialog instanciando el servicio de nuevo y accediendo a su getter.

Algo así:

Componente 1:

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private vs: VideoService) {}

openDialog(url: string) {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialogComponent);

  this.vs.setUrl = url;

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
  });
}
```

Componente con diálogo:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-content-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-content-example-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-content-example-dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogContentExampleDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  url_video: string;

  constructor(private vs: VideoService) { 
    this.url_video = this.vs.getUrl;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Servicio:

```
export class VideoService {

  url: string;
  
  constructor() { }

  set setUrl(val:string) {
    this.url = val;
  }

  get getUrl():string{
    return this.url;
  }
}
```